# Polymer: How to define constant variables on a per-file basis?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1.0 and I am in need of some constant variables in my `.js` file. Example:

```
const REQUEST_URL = '/test';

Polymer({
  ...
  // use REQUEST_URL a few times
  ...
});
```

The problem with this approach is that if `REQUEST_URL` is defined multiple times in different files, they will collide and result in `SyntaxError: Identifier 'REQUEST_URL' has already been declared`.

What is the preferred way to define constant variables on a per-file basis in Polymer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constants that differ between files, just use a private property by prefixing with `_`. For constants that need shared, you could do the same thing but in a behavior in a separate file that can be imported into any file that needs those constants.

```
properties: {
  _requestUrl: {
    type: String,
    value: '/test'
  }
}
```

For behavior do the same thing but treat as behavior. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors

Comment: I don't think properties can be assigned in this way. You'd have to do `properties: { _requestUrl: { type: String, value: 'test' } }`. This should be clarified in the answer.